# How to use previous span top and left positions to place other span so they don't overlap each others?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to make a tag cloud out of specific hard-coded words with Javascript.

So for this very light-weight simple HTML code:

```
<body>
    <article></article>
</body>
```

And this very few CSS:

```
article {
    width: 750px;
    height: 750px;
    border: 1px solid red;

}
article span {
    position: absolute;
}
```

And these hard-coded data:

```
var motsHorizontaux = [
    'prix',
    'transmission',
    // ...
    'valeur',
    'fiscal'
];

var colors = [
    'MediumPurple',
    'MediumSeaGreen',
    // ...
    'PaleGreen',
    'PaleTurquoise',
];

var fonts = [
    'Arial',
    'Helvetica',
    // ...
    'Courrier New',
    'Lucida Console'
];
```

And these Javascript declarations:

```
var random = function(min, max) {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min, 0);
}
Number.prototype.between = function(a, b) {
    var min = Math.min.apply(Math, [a, b]),
        max = Math.max.apply(Math, [a, b])
    ;
    return this > min && this < max;
};
```

I came up with this jQuery code:

```
jQuery(function($) {

    var $area = $('article')
        , minSize = 21
        , maxSize = 48
    ; 
    for(var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {

        var $mot = $('<span/>').text(motsHorizontaux[i]).css({
            'color': colors[i],
            'font-family': fonts[i],
            'font-size': random(minSize, maxSize)
        });
        $mot.appendTo('article');

        var topMaxPosition = $area.height() - $mot.height();
        var leftMaxPosition = $area.width() - $mot.width();

        $mot.css({
            'top': random($area.position().top, topMaxPosition),
            'left': random($area.position().left, leftMaxPosition)
        }); 

        // ...
    }    

});
```

All this code outputs:

[image]

As you can see, words come up nicely. There's only one drawback, some of them are overlapping each other. So to correct this, I made an attempt and I managed to store all words coordinates in two arrays with the following code:

```
$mots = $area.find('> span');
$mots.each(function(j, el) {
    var $el = $(el);
    var previousTop = $el.position().top;
    var previousLeft = $el.position().left;
    var previousBottom = previousTop + $el.height();
    var previousRight = previousLeft + $el.width();

    while(true) {
        var newPositionTop = random($area.position().top, topMaxPosition);
        var newPositionLeft = random($area.position().left, leftMaxPosition);
        var newPositionBottom = newPositionTop + $mot.height();
        var newPositionRight = newPositionLeft + $mot.width();
        if(
            !newPositionTop.between(previousTop, previousBottom) &&
            !newPositionBottom.between(previousTop, previousBottom) &&
            !newPositionLeft.between(previousLeft, previousRight) &&
            !newPositionRight.between(previousLeft, previousRight)
        ) {
            $mot.css({
                'top': newPositionTop,
                'left': newPositionLeft
            });
            break;

        }
    }
});
```

<sup>(this snippet is nested into the outer `for() {}` loop)</sup>

But this still makes the words overlap each others (even if I have to admit, there are less than before). I think I have a misconception as the `while(true) {}` loop will apply only with the very previous word (`$el`) thus erasing the check (the `if( && && && ) {}` in the loop) for all words before. Can someone help me fix my code? Here's the code snippet:

```js
  jQuery(function($) {
    var random = function(min, max) {
      return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min, 0);
    }
    Number.prototype.between = function(a, b) {
      var min = Math.min.apply(Math, [a, b]),
        max = Math.max.apply(Math, [a, b]);
      return this > min && this < max;
    };

    var motsHorizontaux = [
      'prix',
      'transmission',
      'finances',
      'administratif',
      'process',
      'évaluation',
      'performance',
      'dirigeant',
      'prévisionnel',
      'anticipation',
      'adaptation',
      'suivi',
      'contrôle',
      'écarts',
      'clignotant',
      'budget',
      'assistance',
      'statut',
      'social',
      'optimisation',
      'projet',
      'valeur',
      'fiscal'
    ];

    var colors = [
      'MediumPurple',
      'MediumSeaGreen',
      'MediumSlateBlue',
      'MediumSpringGreen',
      'MediumTurquoise',
      'SpringGreen',
      'SteelBlue',
      'Tan',
      'Teal',
      'Thistle',
      'Tomato',
      'Turquoise',
      'Violet',
      'Navy',
      'OldLace',
      'Olive',
      'OliveDrab',
      'Orange',
      'OrangeRed',
      'Orchid',
      'PaleGoldenRod',
      'PaleGreen',
      'PaleTurquoise',
    ];

    var fonts = [
      'Arial',
      'Helvetica',
      'Arial Black',
      'Comic Sans MS',
      'Impact',
      'Charcoal',
      'Lucida Sans Unicode',
      'Lucida Grande',
      'Tahoma',
      'Geneva',
      'Trebuchet MS',
      'Verdana',
      'Courrier New',
      'Lucida Console'
    ];

    var $area = $('article'),
      minSize = 21,
      maxSize = 36;
    for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
      console.log('Mot : ' + motsHorizontaux[i]);

      var $mot = $('<span/>').text(motsHorizontaux[i]).css({
        'color': colors[i],
        'font-family': fonts[i],
        'font-size': random(minSize, maxSize)
      });
      $mot.appendTo('article');

      var topMaxPosition = $area.height() - $mot.height();
      var leftMaxPosition = $area.width() - $mot.width();

      $mot.css({
        'top': random($area.position().top, topMaxPosition),
        'left': random($area.position().left, leftMaxPosition)
      });
      $mots = $area.find('> span');
      $mots.each(function(j, el) {
        var $el = $(el);
        var previousTop = $el.position().top;
        var previousLeft = $el.position().left;
        var previousBottom = previousTop + $el.height();
        var previousRight = previousLeft + $el.width();

        while (true) {
          var newPositionTop = random($area.position().top, topMaxPosition);
          var newPositionLeft = random($area.position().left, leftMaxPosition);
          var newPositionBottom = newPositionTop + $mot.height();
          var newPositionRight = newPositionLeft + $mot.width();
          if (!newPositionTop.between(previousTop, previousBottom) &&
            !newPositionBottom.between(previousTop, previousBottom) &&
            !newPositionLeft.between(previousLeft, previousRight) &&
            !newPositionRight.between(previousLeft, previousRight)
          ) {
            $mot.css({
              'top': newPositionTop,
              'left': newPositionLeft
            });
            break;
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

```css
article {
  width: 750px;
  height: 750px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

article span {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article></article>
```

Thanks for the attention you guys would bring to my problem.

Comment: As an aside, that seems an unnecessarily complicated way to call Math.min() and .max(). Why not call them directly? Math.min(a,b)

Comment: I just want to mention here that there is a good d3js script for this https://www.jasondavies.com/wordcloud/

Comment: @nnnnnn: What do you mean? Where should I use `Math.min()` and `Math.max()`?

Comment: @Varon: Thanks for the link, I'll check that out. I'm still interested in an answer to my problem though :)

Comment: You're already using them in your .between() method. I'm just saying that invoking them via .apply() seems over-complicated.

Comment: @nnnnnn: Right, to be honest, this was just a copy/paste from another question on SO :)

Comment: Maybe you don't want to be placing them _completely_ randomly to begin with then? Otherwise you'll have to do rectangle intersection detection after each attempt to place a word/tag, and it would become increasingly difficult to place larger words with a shrinking amount of space.

Comment: another solution would be to let them move slowly around, so they do not always overlap another

Comment: @MichaelOakley: You are absolutely right and I am aware of that. That's why the dimensions of the red square are absolutely open to be wider. It is the very *do rectangle intersection detection after each attempt* you are mentionning that I would like to achieve.

Comment: @GCyrillus: What do you mean by *let them move slowly around*? Using `transitions` in CSS?

Comment: i did not think about animation, but delayed and based on transform or relative, why not . I thought first that relative positionning was helping to integrate in any page since size will adapt to room avalaible and content . basicly with transition + animation : https://jsfiddle.net/n0jrd9sy/3/ (to give you an idea), else retart the js every 5 seconds or so just keep the transition

Comment: @D4VID then you probably want a function like this to compare corner positions.
`function intersectRect(rect1, rect2) {
        return !(rect2.left > rect1.right || 
           rect2.right < rect1.left || 
           rect2.top > rect1.bottom ||
           rect2.bottom < rect1.top);
    }`

Comment: @MichaelOakley: Could you make an answer? If it works, I won't hesitate to accept it :)

Comment: the idea of looping the function   https://jsfiddle.net/n0jrd9sy/4/ ....

Answer (score 1):

If you use position:relative for your cloud tags, it might be easier to manage in the flow and inside a fluid box.

*More like a personnal opinion than an advise and an horrible and quick fix to js .*

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var random = function(min, max) {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min, 0);
  }
  Number.prototype.between = function(a, b) {
    var min = Math.min.apply(Math, [a, b]),
      max = Math.max.apply(Math, [a, b]);
    return this > min && this < max;
  };

  var motsHorizontaux = [
    'prix',
    'transmission',
    'finances',
    'administratif',
    'process',
    'évaluation',
    'performance',
    'dirigeant',
    'prévisionnel',
    'anticipation',
    'adaptation',
    'suivi',
    'contrôle',
    'écarts',
    'clignotant',
    'budget',
    'assistance',
    'statut',
    'social',
    'optimisation',
    'projet',
    'valeur',
    'fiscal'
  ];

  var colors = [
    'MediumPurple',
    'MediumSeaGreen',
    'MediumSlateBlue',
    'MediumSpringGreen',
    'MediumTurquoise',
    'SpringGreen',
    'SteelBlue',
    'Tan',
    'Teal',
    'Thistle',
    'Tomato',
    'Turquoise',
    'Violet',
    'Navy',
    'OldLace',
    'Olive',
    'OliveDrab',
    'Orange',
    'OrangeRed',
    'Orchid',
    'PaleGoldenRod',
    'PaleGreen',
    'PaleTurquoise',
  ];

  var fonts = [
    'Arial',
    'Helvetica',
    'Arial Black',
    'Comic Sans MS',
    'Impact',
    'Charcoal',
    'Lucida Sans Unicode',
    'Lucida Grande',
    'Tahoma',
    'Geneva',
    'Trebuchet MS',
    'Verdana',
    'Courrier New',
    'Lucida Console'
  ];

  var $area = $('article'),
    minSize = 21,
    maxSize = 36;
  for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {

    var $mot = $('<span/>').text(motsHorizontaux[i]).css({
      'color': colors[i],
      'font-family': fonts[i],
      'font-size': random(minSize, maxSize)
    });
    $mot.appendTo('article');

    var topPosition = $area.height() / 4 - $mot.height();
    var leftPosition = $mot.width() /3;

    $mot.css({
      'top': random(0, topPosition),
      'left': random('0', leftPosition)
    });

  }

  var $mots = $area.find('span');
  var leftPositions = [];
  var topPositions = [];
  $mots.each(function(i, el) {

    var $el = $(el);
    var previousTop = 0;
    var previousLeft = 0;
    var previousBottom = 0;
    var previousRight = 0;

    leftPositions[i] = [previousLeft, previousRight];
    topPositions[i] = [previousTop, previousBottom];

  });

});
```

```css
article {
  padding: 2em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
article span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article></article>
```

or the loop idea: https://jsfiddle.net/n0jrd9sy/4/

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm checking that out but I'm willing to read about other solutions in pure JS as I would like to keep the `position: absolute`. Still open to other answers then :). Also, why `/ 4` and `/ 3`?

Comment: @D4V1D as is aid a quick fix :), it is only to make sure they stay witin the box and don't stand all the way out  i added also a padding

Comment: I made the change and removing both `width` and `height` from `article {}` in CSS made a rectangle instead of a square. Which is not what I seek for. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 1):

Collision detection:

```
function intersectRect(rect1, rect2) { 
    return !(rect2.left > rect1.right || 
        rect2.right < rect1.left || 
        rect2.top > rect1.bottom || 
        rect2.bottom < rect1.top); 
}
```

There's some interesting code in this plugin you might want to consider.
https://github.com/mistic100/jQCloud/blob/master/src/jqcloud.js#L184

Comment: Thanks for answering. What are exactly `rect1` and `rect2`? Objects? jQuery objects?

Comment: They are just simple javascript objects.